# How to make an HTTP request within router.get method in Express

Tags: api, rest, express

I'm making a simple API in express js. I've an end point where I'll make a call to GitHub api int turn. My Front-end application will utilize it. Here is my code:

**api.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
...
var http = require('http');
var https = require("https");

router.get('/github', function (req, res) {

    // APPROACH 1: Failed : fetch is not defined
    // fetch('https://api.github.com/users/tmtanzeel')
    //     .then(response => response.json())
    //     .then(json => console.log(json))


    // APPROACH 2: Failed : throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    /*try {
        https.get('https://api.github.com/users/tmtanzeel',function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        })
    } catch (error) {
        ...
    }*/
});
```

Both my approaches are failing. I've almost no experience with Express. Please picth in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method is almost corrent. Add the  error handler and send to the caller the data you just received.

```
https.get('https://api.github.com/users/tmtanzeel',function (apiRes) {

  apiRes.pipe(res);

}).on('error', (e) => {

      console.error(e);
      res.status(500).send('Something went wrong');
});
```

Handling the response (stream) received from the API call can be done in two ways.

1. Using pipes which is automatic
2. Handle read events and manage the data writing manually

I have used the first approach.

However, it is very well recommended that you get sound knowledge in handling Streams if you use Node JS. Streams are the basis of Node JS requests and responses.

https://nodejs.dev/learn/nodejs-streams

Comment: very well explained. Thanks for your time. This worked.

Comment: I'm using your solution in the production. I'm facing other (unrelated issues) Can you plz look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69409586/how-to-make-a-get-call-to-api-github-with-express-server

Comment: I'm asking your help because youve good knowledge in this field.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Express to handle incoming requests.
(for example if your webapp fetches data from your (express) server).
Read the docs: http://expressjs.com

Your first attempt failed because `fetch` is an implementation of the web-browser, not one of nodejs.

If you want to use fetch try: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch 
its a well documented, easy to use fetch function.

Answer (score 0):

From your examples, all seems fine except I can't see you sending the returned data to the client.

You can try something similar like adding `res.send(data)` to send the data and make it available on the `/github` route

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Philip. I've got my answer for now and I've accepted it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow